# Event handler called only on second click

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I'm building a dynamic button view, which adds buttons programmatically depending on the amount of items in the database. Like a simple workflow engine. On the first page call the event handler works like expected. The new page with the new item is builded and returned to the client. On the second postback the event handler is NOT called and the view keeps the same items. By reclicking  the same button (third postback), the breakpoint in the event handler is hitted.

My issue is why is the event handler not called even if i'm rebuilding the page (override OnInit()) on each post back?

For information: The methods `LoadViewWithAlphabeticalDatasource()` and `LoadViewWithWorkflowItem()` does quite the same, so i deleted one in section below. The events are added in same way.

Code:

```
<pre>
   namespace EPS.Web.View.Article
   {
       public class DynamicGridView : BasePage, IDynamicGridView
       {


           protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
           {
               Presenter = new DynamicGridPresenter(this);
               if (IsPostBack)
               {
                   if (Presenter.Step smallerthan 2)
                   {
                       LoadViewWithAlphabeticalDatasource();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       LoadViewWithWorkflowItem();
                   }
               }
           }

           [PageMethod]
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               if(!IsPostBack)
               {
                   SetSubmenuVisible = false;
                   Presenter.InitView();
                   PrepareView();
               }
               AddEvents();
               AddLabels();
               PageMethodsEngine.InvokeMethod(this);
           }



           private void Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               Presenter.StepEngine(DynamicGridPresenter.BACK, string.Empty, string.Empty);
               PrepareView();
           }

           private void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               Presenter.StepEngine(DynamicGridPresenter.CANCEL, string.Empty, string.Empty);
               PrepareView();
           }

           private void ForwardString(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               Presenter.StepEngine(DynamicGridPresenter.FORWARD, ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument, string.Empty);
               PrepareView();
           }

          private void ForwardWorkflowItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              Presenter.StepEngine(DynamicGridPresenter.FORWARD, string.Empty, ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
              PrepareView();
          }

          protected void PrepareView()
          {
              phDynamicGridView.Controls.Clear();
              if (Presenter.Step smallerthan 2)
              {
                  LoadViewWithAlphabeticalDatasource();
              }
              else
              {
                  LoadViewWithWorkflowItem();
              }
          }

          private void LoadViewWithWorkflowItem()
          {
              var table = new HtmlTable();
              table.Attributes.Add("class", "tableDynamicGrid");
              int max = GetRowLength(WODatasource.Count);
              int temp = 1;
              int actualPosition = 0;
              int itr = 1;
              var tr = new HtmlTableRow();

              if (WODatasource.Count == 0)
              {
                  phDynamicGridView.Controls.Add(new HtmlTable());
                  return;
              }

              foreach (WorkflowItem s in WODatasource)
              {
                  if (actualPosition biggerOrEqual MaxLength && temp smallerOrEqual max)
                  {
                      table.Rows.Add(tr);
                      actualPosition = 0;
                      temp++;
                      tr = new HtmlTableRow();
                  }


                  actualPosition++;

                  var cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                  // cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cellDynamicGrid");
                  var btn = new LinkButton
                                {
                                    CommandArgument = s.Oid.ToString(),
                                    Text = s.SelectionItem.Name /*, CssClass = "linkButtonDynamicGrid"*/
                                };
                  btn.Click += ForwardWorkflowItem;

                  cell.Controls.Add(btn);
                  tr.Cells.Add(cell);

                  if (itr == WODatasource.Count && temp smallerOrEqual max)
                  {
                      while (itr biggerOrEqual WODatasource.Count && itr smallerThan max*MaxLength)
                      {
                          tr.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell());
                          itr++;
                      }
                      table.Rows.Add(tr);
                      phDynamicGridView.Controls.Add(table);
                      return;
                  }
                  itr++;
              }
          }

       }
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank everbody for helping me out. I found the solution:

I didn't know that the dynamically created button needs a ID value. I suggested that Asp know wich button is created. Unfortunately i was wrong. It seems that .NET compares the ID on the buttons and not the position in ControlTree.

I added

```
new Button{ID = itr.ToString()}
```

Now when server rebuilds the site, eventhandler are hitted.

regards
x.

Answer (score 4):

OnInit happens *before* LoadPostData is called, and this is the reason it appears to work on the second click. What's actually happening is that you are handling an event from a previous postback.

1. Page_Init
2. LoadViewState
3. **LoadPostData**
4. Page_Load
5. RaisePostDataChangedEvent
6. RaisePostBackEvent
7. Page_PreRender
8. SaveViewState
9. Page_Render
10. Page_UnLoad

This is a simplified version of events from Asp.net 1.1; 2.0 has some extra events inserted inbetween, like OnPreInit. The order remains though.

You must use an event from Load or later. Some people choose PreRender, but convention for DataBinding is in Load.

**UPDATE**

I see you are dynamically adding controls to the controls tree. This is fraught with pitfalls (but is perfectly workable.)

a) ensure you add the dynamic controls EVERY time the page loads, not just on postback. Postback/viewstate persists STATE (i.e. data), not objects. You should add them in OnInit (OnLoad works too, but it is more troublesome to maintain). You are currently only adding on postback, this is why the 2nd postback works (and not the first)

b) only initialize the dynamic controls ONCE, like you would any other control - on [!IsPostBack], in Load.

-Oisin

Comment: Are all of the controls involved declarative in the aspx/ascx? i.e. you are not dynamically adding controls somewhere in the code? If you dynamically add controls, things get hairier still.

Comment: Ah, I see you ARE doing that. If you dynamically add controls to the page, you must ensure they always exist in the control tree before you can handle an event for them.

Comment: To further clarify, make sure you add the controls to the controls collection EVERY time the page loads (regardless of PostBack state), in OnInit. But only set the DEFAULT values - if needed - the first time [!PostBack]

Comment: protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            Presenter = new DynamicGridPresenter(this);
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SetSubmenuVisible = false;
                Presenter.InitView();
            }
            PrepareView();
        }

Comment: 1. On postpack i rebuild the site with the items stored in the session. --> adds event handler to my programmatically added buttons. --> PrepareView();
2. The event handler is called by the button with the needed command argument.
3. A Query is executed on db to get new items with same command argument and stored in session
4.  The new view is builded with the new buttons --> PrepareView()
5. Page is sent back to client

I need to call the PrepareView() twice. The first call is to know which event has been fired. The second call is needed to build the new html table with the buttons.
TIA

Comment: I cant really spend the time to understand what you're doing - ultimately, whatever it is, it is wrong. What you need to do is to read up on the correct methodology and apply it to your problem. Grab a coffee and take a read of this great article on the subject:

http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Comment: Anyway-Thank you very much for your support. I'll read the article. Hope it helps. Since 2 days on this *#¦@~^ issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problems of this kind are almost always a result of wiring up the event handlers in the wrong place in the page lifecycle.

Comment: I mean i add the event handler in the onInit Method with same items. Till now it worked fine with repeater, datagrids etc. But now i do not know how to solve this.

Comment: You may need to do the wireup in a different place now.  I had a similar problem a couple weeks ago, and I eventually solved it by trying out the event wireup in different places.  It's a tricky thing because not every control behaves in the same way.

Comment: What does "AddEvents();" do? Isn't it rebinding all events? Would better fit in (!Page.Ispostback) i think

Comment: I've got to buttons defined on the aspx page (back & cancel).

AddEvent(){
btnCancel.Click+= btnCancel_Click;
btnBack.Click+=btnBack_Click;
}

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I tried lots of solutions, but in the end I noticed that one of the textboxes on my webform was posting back to the server, which messed things up. It was a hard bug to catch because I didn't mean to have my textbox do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ID variable without declaration this maybe couse of the problem. change the name of the your ID variable name.